# Web2py layout cant contain form

Tags: web2py

I wanted to add forms in header, so I tried to add them to layout.html. But it wont work as i would have to add form to all the controllers.

Is there a shorter way so that i wont have to copy my code again and again

Comment: What does the form do, and what is supposed to happen when the user submits the form (i.e., should submission redirect to a particular page, or should the current page reload)?

Comment: it is a search bar,and it should redirect to other page

Answer (score 0):

Since it is just a search box, one simple option is just to code the form HTML directly in the layout:

```
<form action="{{=URL('default', 'search')}}" method="get">
    <input name="keyword" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then your `search` function can access the keyword via `request.vars.keyword`:

In the `default.py` controller:

```
def search():
    keyword = request.vars.keyword
    ...
```

Comment: Actually, search box was just an example. I wanted to know that if i create a header, that needs some data from the controller, is there any shorter way. One way that i could think was to instead of controller, write all the function in the view itself(within {{ }}). But that does not look good. Can you suggest any other method

Comment: Please explain in detail what you are really trying to do. What do you mean that the header needs data from the controller? If you just need to put a form in the layout and have it submit to a particular controller action, the above answer is the way to do it. If you are trying to do something else, please provide a specific example of the workflow you need to achieve.